# Ubuntu hangs and my Monitor Turning off and on

Tags: installation, wubi

I'm Newbie on Ubuntu :) I've tried to install ubuntu with Wubi ,after downloading the OS it prompts "Reboot Now" after rebooting ubuntu starts to install while installing the Mouse cursor Appears and hangs and suddenly My Monitor turned off and on again and again i cant proceed with the installation I'm stuck, I'm in running Windows 7 2gb ram,500gb hd,amd-apu 3400..

Comment: Did you try installing it without Wubi?

Comment: Boot with `nomodeset`: http://askubuntu.com/a/257917/14916 Then look to install proprietary graphics drivers.

Comment: Yes,via USB bootable..same problem :(